# Fatal Error Visual Studio Code / GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, fatal-error, macos-sierra

Ok, I'll try to do my best. I'm using git on MacOS Sierra and I have a problem. When I opened git, instead typing "git add (and the folder that I want to use to work)" I typed "git add ." . This action apparently created a new .git folder and added ALL the files from my Macbook. So, using Visual Studio Code, in the git section, apears 5000 changes not confirmed and a fatal error. How can i revert the first action? Sorry for my english.

Comment: Your question must be in English.

Comment: Or you can post it here: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

the `.git` folder was already here (it is created by `git init` or `git clone`)

since you did not commit yet, you can try `git reset`.
if you are not happy with that, then try `git reset --hard` (that will revert to the latest commit, and you will lose **all** your uncommited changes.

Comment: I typed both but it didnt resolved the problem. Visual Studio Code keeps showing me the message "Alert, the repository Git '/User/Eze' contain many active changes, only Git characteristics subset will be enabled." 

I dont know how to remove all this files without erasing them from VScode. 

https://imgur.com/v9b1PWF

Comment: what does `git status` say ?